# How to mask first 6 and last 4 digits for a credit card number in .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, regex, security

I'm very new to regex And I'm trying to use a regular expression to turn a credit card number which will be part of a conversation into something like 492900******2222

As it can come from any conversation it might contain string next to it or might have an inconsistent format, so essentially all of the below should be formatted to the example above:

- hello my number is492900001111222
- number is 4929000011112222ok?
- 4929 0000 1111 2222
- 4929-0000-1111-2222

It needs to be a regular expression which extracts the capture group of which I will then be able to use a MatchEvaluator to turn all digits (excluding non digits) which are not the first 6 and last 4 into a *

I've seen many examples here on stack overflow for PHP and JS but none which helps me resolve this issue.

Any guidance will be appreciated

*UPDATE*

I need to expand upon an existing implementation which uses MatchEvaluator to mask each character that is not the first 6 or last 4 and ideally I dont want to change the MatchEvaluator and just make the masking flexible based on the regular expression, see this for an example https://dotnetfiddle.net/J2LCo0

*UPDATE 2*

@Matt.G and @CAustin answers do resolve what I asked for but I am hitting another barrier where I cant have it be so strict.  The final captured group needs to only take into account the digits and as such maintain the format of the input text.
So for example:

If some types in my card number is 99 9988 8877776666 the output from the evaluation should be 99 9988 ******666666

OR
my card number is 9999-8888-7777-6666 it should output 9999-88**-****-6666.

Is this possible?

Changed the list to include items that are in my unit tests https://dotnetfiddle.net/tU6mxQ

Comment: What are the pattern requirements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Regex: `(?<=\d{4}\d{2})\d{2}\d{4}(?=\d{4})|(?<=\d{4}( |-)\d{2})\d{2}\1\d{4}(?=\1\d{4})`

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0XMluq/3)

[C# Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cVEAKi)

Explanation:

```
2 alternative regexes
(?<=\d{4}\d{2})\d{2}\d{4}(?=\d{4}) - to handle cardnumbers without any separators (- or <space>)
(?<=\d{4}( |-)\d{2})\d{2}\1\d{4}(?=\1\d{4}) - to handle cardnumbers with separator (- or <space>)

1st Alternative (?<=\d{4}\d{2})\d{2}\d{4}(?=\d{4})
    Positive Lookbehind (?<=\d{4}\d{2}) - matches text that has 6 digits immediately behind it
    \d{2} matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
        {2} Quantifier — Matches exactly 2 times
    \d{4} matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
        {4} Quantifier — Matches exactly 4 times
    Positive Lookahead (?=\d{4}) - matches text that is followed immediately by 4 digits
        Assert that the Regex below matches
            \d{4} matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
            {4} Quantifier — Matches exactly 4 times

2nd Alternative (?<=\d{4}( |-)\d{2})\d{2}\1\d{4}(?=\1\d{4})

    Positive Lookbehind (?<=\d{4}( |-)\d{2}) - matches text that has (4 digits followed by a separator followed by 2 digits) immediately behind it
    1st Capturing Group ( |-) - get the separator as a capturing group, this is to check the next occurence of the separator using \1
    \1 matches the same text as most recently matched by the 1st capturing group (separator, in this case)
    Positive Lookahead (?=\1\d{4}) - matches text that is followed by separator and 4 digits
```

Comment: Why `(?: |-)` instead of just `[ -]?`? Also, you don't need to capture the parts that will be overwritten.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and even though it does the credit card numbers, I have to use the MatchEvaluator as I am essentially expanding upon an existing solution.  This  snippet is what I am trying to do: https://dotnetfiddle.net/J2LCo0 .  I think im just miss-understanding regular expressions, I need the regular expression to only comeback matching the part of the number that needs to be masked.

Comment: @Bynho, I've updated the answer with your new requirements

Comment: Note that `\d{4}(?<=\d{4})` = `\d{4}`

Comment: Brilliant, thanks @Matt.G.  could you explain how it's working?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, thanks..it was a mistake..changed it to a lookahead..updated the answer and links

Comment: Thanks @Matt.G.  Just as a follow up, how would I be able to make it so that it ignores dashes and spaces from the capturing group so that entries like this would still work:  4929 9 999 88887777 or 4929-9999-8888-7777 where the capturing group would be ** **** or ****-**** .  Notice how the output format has not changed based on the captured group.  Hope Im making sense :)

Answer (score 2):

If performance is a concern, here's a pattern that only goes through 94 steps, instead of the other answer's 473, by avoiding lookaround and alternation:

`\d{4}[ -]?\d{2}\K\d{2}[ -]?\d{4}`

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/0XMluq/4

Edit: In C#'s regex flavor, the following pattern can be used instead, since C# allows variable length lookbehind.

`(?<=\d{4}[ -]?\d{2})\d{2}[ -]?\d{4}`

[Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%5Cd%7B4%7D%5B%20-%5D%3F%5Cd%7B2%7D%29%5Cd%7B2%7D%5B%20-%5D%3F%5Cd%7B4%7D&i=hello%20my%20number%20is4929000011112222%0D%0Anumber%20is%204929000011112222ok%3F%0D%0A4929%200000%201111%202222%0D%0A4929-0000-1111-2222%0D%0A)

Comment: C# (.NET) regex does not support `\K` construct